# ocaml jbuilder build object file without associated opam project

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to use jbuilder to build an extremely simple project (based on the example in the jbuilder project itself). Jbuilder seems to have some OPAM integration / OPAM awareness built-in. How do I disable that and direct jbuilder to just build specific files I ask for in the build directory?

Here is the `jbuild` in `./jbuild`

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(library
    ((name        hello_world)
     (public_name hello_world)))
```

And here is `hello_world.ml`

```
let message = "hello world!"
```

When I run `jbuilder build --only hello_world --root .` (which I thought would disable the opam-related logic)

I got the error

```
File "jbuild", line 5, characters 5-30:
Error: You cannot declare items to be installed without adding a <package>.opam file at the root of your project.
To declare elements to be installed as part of package "hello_world", add a "hello_world.opam" file at the root of your project.
Exit 1
```

The only thing I'm after here is the `hello_world.cmo` file ... and possibly a log of the commands that jbuilder executed in order to produce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way to disable that behaviour, but the simplest way to use it is to just create an empty `hello_world.opam` file (or whatever your `public_name` is):

```
touch hello_world.opam
```